# Recursive code results in allowed memory size to be exhausted

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, memory-leaks, nested-object

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E87nG.png)[Expected input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2ycY.png)I am required to make a nested dependent object from an array of objects where the innermost object will contain a key-value pair. I have done that by array manipulation where I have first stored the object values and key-value in a 2d array and then using this 2d array (trimmed array), two rows with identical parent index values are merged together.

```
function recursiveMerge($rowIdx,$columnIdx,$trimmedArray,$parentArray){
        /*base condition - when no column left to traverse recursively*/
        if($columnIdx<1){
            return($trimmedArray);
        } elseif($rowIdx+1 == count($trimmedArray)){
        /*
            when all the rows are merged for a dropdown column, it calls the
            function for the parent dropdown column
        */
            $trimmedArray=array_values($trimmedArray);
            $parentArray=array_values($parentArray);
            //the unique dropdown values are nested inside its parent column
            $trimmedArray[$rowIdx][$columnIdx-1]=array($trimmedArray[$rowIdx][$columnIdx-1]=>$trimmedArray[$rowIdx][$columnIdx]);
            return(recursiveMerge(0,--$columnIdx,$trimmedArray,$parentArray));
        } else {
                /*
            the rows which have identical parent dependent keys are merged together into 
            the first row and the second row is deleted(unset)
            */
            if($parentArray[$rowIdx][$columnIdx]===$parentArray[$rowIdx+1][$columnIdx]){
                // $trimmedArray[$rowIdx][$columnIdx]=$trimmedArray[$rowIdx][$columnIdx] + $trimmedArray[$rowIdx+1][$columnIdx];
                $trimmedArray[$rowIdx][$columnIdx]=array_merge_custom($trimmedArray[$rowIdx][$columnIdx], $trimmedArray[$rowIdx+1][$columnIdx]);
                unset($parentArray[$rowIdx+1]);         
                $parentArray=array_values($parentArray);

                unset($trimmedArray[$rowIdx+1]);            
                $trimmedArray=array_values($trimmedArray);

                return(recursiveMerge($rowIdx,$columnIdx,$trimmedArray,$parentArray));
            }
            else{
                $trimmedArray[$rowIdx][$columnIdx-1]=array($trimmedArray[$rowIdx][$columnIdx-1]=>$trimmedArray[$rowIdx][$columnIdx]);
                return(recursiveMerge(++$rowIdx,$columnIdx,$trimmedArray,$parentArray));
            }

        }
    }
```

However, for an array of objects with smaller size works fine. Input data with the larger count is resulting in Fatal error: ALlowed memory size exhausted.

Comment: I can help you if you provide a concrete input and expected output

Comment: I have attached screenshots of input and output

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Save memory by minimizing recursions or using a different, less memory intensive algorithm to solve your problem.
2. Give you PHP-process more memory. See [`memory_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) in your `php.ini`.

But keep in mind: the recursion depth in PHP is not unlimited!